# i18next <Trans> avoid retranslation of nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I am using i18next with React for my project. For most of the translations I use the `t()` function with normal text. However, for some cases I would prefer to use the `<Trans />` component.

I prepared some example below:

```
function Example() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const reusableComponent = <p>{t('TranslateMeOnlyOnce')}</p>;

    return (
        <>
            {reusableComponent}
            <Trans i18nKey={'OnlyOnceWrapper'}>
                The reusable component says {reusableComponent}
            </Trans>
        </>
    )
}
```

Which expect would my ranslation file to look something like this:

```
...
TranslateMeOnlyOnce: 'Translate me only once',
OnlyOnceWrapper: 'The reusable component says <1>Translate me only once</1>',
...
```

However, as you can see I would be required to translate the text of the nested component twice. I would really like to just translate the `The reusable component says {reusableComponent}` in the second translation string and not all of the first translation string for another time.

For those wondering why I would want to do this, lets say `const reusableComponent` is a Create Button with some function to create a new entry placed at the top of the Screen. When however, there is no entry displayed in my list of entries I want to display a message saying something like: *'Unfortunately there is no entry yet. Click on [CreateButtonIsDisplayedHere] to create a new entry'*.

Let's say I experience that users find a translation 'New' instead of 'Create' more useful or the other way round, I would want to change only the translation of the button and not every other place containing this button.

I also found myself a solution to this issue already, however, in my experience this is super ugly to maintain as I need to pass the content as string and not as React child Element which pretty much take all advantages of using the `<Trans />` Component and I could better use the `t()` function using `sprintf`.

```
function UglySolution() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const reusableComponent = <p>{t('Translate me only Once')}</p>;

    return (
        <>
            {reusableComponent}
            <Trans 
                i18nKey={'OnlyOnceWrapper'} 
                components={[reusableComponent]} 
                variables={{ v: t('Translate me only Once') }} 
                defaults='The reusable component says <1>{{v}}</1>'
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

Which would expect my translation file to look something like this:

```
...
TranslateMeOnlyOnce: 'Translate me only once',
OnlyOnceWrapper: 'The reusable component says <1>{{v}}</1>',
...
```

So my question is: Can I make my translation file to look something like the second example I created without using the ugly `<Trans />` component from the second example and more something like the component in the first example I created?

Answer (score 0):

**Resusing translations**

There is a way using the `<Trans />` component as in the first example with reusing previous translations. Using `$t(KeyToAnotherTranslation)` inside the translation string.

This does not fully solve the issue as it's also not too handy to maintain but would be a lot prettier than the second example shown.

```
function Example() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const reusableComponent = <p>{t('TranslateMeOnlyOnce')}</p>;

    return (
        <>
            {reusableComponent}
            <Trans i18nKey={'OnlyOnceWrapper'}>
                The reusable component says {reusableComponent}
            </Trans>
        </>
    )
}
```

*(Taken 1:1 from the code from the question)*

With a translation file looking something like this:

```
...
TranslateMeOnlyOnce: 'Translate me only once',
OnlyOnceWrapper: 'The reusable component says <1>$t(TranslateMeOnlyOnce)</1>',
...
```

[More information](https://www.i18next.com/misc/json-format) about variable usage in i18next.